# In Mule 3.3, How can multiple applications be started and stopped separately without affecting each other?

Tags: mule

I want to deploy two applications (Hello and Bye) under `%MULE_HOME%/apps` by following the standalone hot deployment instructions. How can I start/stop Hello and Bye independently?

1. How to start only the Hello app?
2. Supposing Hello and Bye apps are already running in the same Mule instance how can I stop the Hello app only without effecting the Bye app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Mule Enterprise edition you can start and stop the FLows indepentely. You can also deploy and undeploy applications.

Please check with the below links

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Management+Console

http://www.mulesoft.com/webinars/optimizing-esb-performance-mule-management-console

http://www.mulesoft.com/management-console-mule-esb

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Architecture+of+the+Mule+Management+Console

Comment: thanks.. but i need comamnd to start/stop the app without using mule management console

Answer (score 0):

In my experience including multiple apps in the same apps folder and then installing them as a windows service gives the start/stop control for each app that you are looking for. This does not require the Mule Enterprise edition and works with the Community Edition. I'm attaching a sample script to install the app as a windows service below.

```
@echo off
```

setlocal
REM There is no need to call this if you set the MULE_HOME in your environment properties
REM but you must also define MULE_LIB for the example (see below)
REM or specify the config as a file: URI (see README.txt)

REM This extends the classpath to include the configuration directory
REM Any changes to the files in .\conf will take precedence over those deployed to %MULE_HOME%\lib\user
set MULE_APP=MyMuleApplication
set MULE_APP_LONG=MyMuleApplication
call %MULE3_HOME%\bin\mule install -app sampleAppName